# Как записать символ в строку?

Tags: c++, строки, char

Пытаюсь написать некое жалкое подобие виселицы, за которое меня повешают. Если буква есть в слове её нужно записать в переменную и так сделать для каждой угаданной. Вопрос заключается в том, как это можно сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void word_letters(char word[4])
{
    char letters; //переменная для ввода буквы
    char YesLetters; //переменная для хранения угаданных букв
    cout << endl << "Введите букву: ";
    cin >> letters; //вводим букву

    if (strchr(word, letters)) //если буква есть в заданном слове
    {
        cout << endl << "Загаданная буква присутствует" << endl << endl;

    }

    else //буквы нет
    {
        cout << endl << "Загаданная буква отсутствует" << endl << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int hod = 0; //считаем количество ходов, которое ровно количеству букв
    char word[6] = "world"; //строка для считывания слова
    //игровой цикл, пока количество ходов не станет равно 7
    do
    {
        word_letters(word);
        ++hod;
    }   
    while (hod < 7);
    //если количество ходов равно 7, то press f
    if (hod == 7)
        cout << "Лимит попыток исчерпан( Вы проиграли(" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Создайте что-ли массив и туда записывайте угаданные буквы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос помечен меткой C++, поэтому я заменил в ответе обычные типы на контейнеры STL - вместо массива `char word[6]`, хранящего искомую строку, использую `std::string`, вместо переменной `char YesLetters`, для хранения найденных букв, использую `std::set`:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>

void word_letters(const std::string& word, std::set<char>& YesLetters)
{
  char letter; //переменная для ввода буквы
  cout << endl << "Введите букву: ";
  cin >> letter; //вводим букву

  if (word.find(letter) != string::npos)
  {
    //если буква есть в заданном слове
    cout << endl << "Загаданная буква присутствует" << endl << endl;

    //Добавляем угаданные буквы в набор.
    YesLetters.insert(letter);
  }
  else
  {
    //буквы нет
    cout << endl << "Загаданная буква отсутствует" << endl << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  setlocale(0, "");
  int hod = 0; //считаем количество ходов, которое ровно количеству букв
  std::string word{ "world" }; //строка для считывания слова
                               //игровой цикл, пока количество ходов не станет равно 7
  std::set<char> YesLetters; //переменная для хранения угаданных букв
  do
  {
    word_letters(word, YesLetters);
    ++hod;
  } while (hod < 7);
  //если количество ходов равно 7, то press f
  if (hod == 7)
    cout << "Лимит попыток исчерпан( Вы проиграли(" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Кстати, программа не проверяет что все буквы угаданы. Для этого после каждой угаданной буквы можно проверять равен ли размер набора угаданных букв длине строки.
Ну и программа не проверяет, что пользователь вводит каждую букву всего один раз.